# Flash AS3 custome Dragging using MOUSE_MOVE event

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

I am creating grid based map renderer in AS3 which loads required chunks of PNG images and render them in a container. I've applied scrolling/dragging logic in this app using MOUSE_MOVE event handler. What I do is,

I register bDragging flag in MOUSE_DOWN and position of mouse, 
In every MOUSE_MOVE, I check displacement of mouse and move main map accordingly
Unregister bDragging flag in MOUSE_UP and set position to NaN.

My problem is dragging is quite jerky/shaky.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. following is sample code I'm using.

```
function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     m_bDragging = true;
     m_ptPrevPoint = new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);
}

function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     m_bDragging = false;
     m_ptPrevPoint = null;
}
function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(!m_bDragging || null == m_ptPrevPoint)
    return;

var nDiffX:Number = int(e.stageX - m_ptPrevPoint.x);
var nDiffY:Number = int(e.stageY - m_ptPrevPoint.y);

//Make movement smoother 
//nDiffX = nDiffX * 4) / 4;
//nDiffY = nDiffY * 4) / 4;

if(nDiffX != 0 || nDiffY != 0)
{
    trace("X : " + nDiffX + ", Y : " + nDiffY + ", points-Old " + m_ptPrevPoint + ", New " + new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY) );
    m_oCircle.x += nDiffX;
    m_oCircle.y += nDiffY;

    m_ptPrevPoint = new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);

    e.updateAfterEvent();
}
else
    trace("not moved - X : " + nDiffX + ", Y : " + nDiffY+ ", points-Old " + m_ptPrevPoint + ", New " + new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY)) }
```

Please check FLA file here...made in Flash CS3. Please note if mouse is on circle it will jerk like hell but if you drag it from outside of circle, It will go smoother!

[Sample FLA](http://www.4shared.com/file/134983108/b38dc041/DragDrop.html)

Comment: One thing to try would be to _not_ create a new point every time. Just change the x to e.stageX and y to e.stageY for m_ptPrevPoint. Otherwise, can't say that I see a problem; it seems pretty straightforward (though I'm curious what m_oCircle contains; is it the entire set of gridded images?).

Comment: No Michael, Circle is just object for this sample code, it contains nothing but a drawn circle!!! ;)

And yes, creating point everytime is a glitch in sample code, but I don't see any reason that creating any problem.

please, look at my edits and sample code.

Comment: I only have Flash MX (and Flex), so I won't be able to use your FLA. The only thing I noticed that _may_ help is related to the startDrag and stopDrag methods (nice tutorial here http://www.flashvalley.com/fv_tutorials/updateAfterEvent/). Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Michael for the link. Its nice. but you can see in my code, I already used updateAfterEvent in my code.

Comment: have you tried without "updateAfterEvent"? Maybe the refresh is causing performance-related jerkiness.

Comment: Create a TIMER and get rid of MOUSE_MOVE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys, I figured out the problem!

actually this might be some bug of adobe, I was strangely getting some odd coordinates and that was the reason movement was not smooth. I converted stageX and stageY using localToGlobal and everything became smoother!!!

now, I dont know why should I be needed to convert stageX/stageY to global. :) my brief changes are as below.

var curPt:Point = DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).localToGlobal(new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY));

var nDiffX:Number = int(curPt.x - m_ptPrevPoint.x);

var nDiffY:Number = int(curPt.y - m_ptPrevPoint.y);

Thanks guys, every help appreciated.

Comment: btw you don't need to cast to an integer: int(curPt.x - m_ptPrevPoint.x)
since you assigning it to a number :-)

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to use MOUSE_MOVE, especially for something as hefty as a map.  I would utilize the TIMER class and specify a preferred interval.  MOUSE_MOVE is known for being resource hungry.

Answer (score 0):

Does my answer in this one help?

[Problems replicating drag-and-drop with mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353361/problems-replicating-drag-and-drop-with-mouse-events/1353489#1353489)

Basically, when you move the mouse, the coordinates of the mouse can sometimes be from a different context that expected, depending on the target of the event. You need to translate the coordinates.

Comment: Hi Glenn, 

I'm considering stageX and stageY only, so I don't think I should translate coordinates.

Comment: I don't have CS3 so I can't see the FLA, but you're probably right. If you're sticking to stageX/Y and the circle's coordinates are not scaled vs. the stage, you should be fine in this case.

Comment: Hey Glenn, Thanks. please see my above comment.