# Flex Smooth Drag of Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm trying to create an object which can be moved in Flex 4.

I tried http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7fed.html but in this most examples actually leaves the actual object (at pause) until the drag is completed, but I'm looking for something where the update will be done/shown while the drag is still on ... in those lines I've tried: [Problems replicating drag-and-drop with mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353361/problems-replicating-drag-and-drop-with-mouse-events) ... but here I dint understand 'what are MouseHelper & EventHelpers'.

Also tried this: [Flash AS3 custome Dragging using MOUSE_MOVE event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469609/flash-as3-custome-dragging-using-mouse-move-event) but the movement is not smooth, very jig-jag.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's [an example](http://wonderfl.net/c/toHm) with 5 ways of dragging (four are commented out):
  
 
 *  `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE`
 *  `Event.ENTER_FRAME`
 
 *   `startDrag(true)`
 
 *   `Timer(10)` which sets `x = mouseX` `y = mouseY` every 10ms 
 
 *  `Timer(100)` which creates a tween to `mouseX, mouseY` instead of applying values 
  
 
If i move the mouse fast enough all of those modes (at 30fps) look as if a sprite is chasing mouse cursor, not being dragged, and also the animation is not smooth at all. However the smoothest animation is provided by tweener, but that mode shows a bigger average distance between mouse cursor and the sprite being dragged.
and btw fast dragging e.g. windows explorer also makes it blink because it doesn't have enough time for rendering at every position

Comment: Thanks for the post. When I click on the swf, the blue square is coming to the mouse position - is that done intentionally!! Also, here I'm trying to apply this 'moving' to a customized video player, will the same work for that .. or it will only work for Sprite, as we are not using it.

Comment: @ user237865 : 1. the blue square moves to the cursor while mouse button is pressed 2. on wonderfl.net you can click the 'fork' button (you'll need to register or login with openID) to copy this code as your own i.e. recieve the ability to edit it on the site and get a new .swf from their server-side compiler every time you edit the source 3. it works for everything that can be passed as a parameter to `addChild()` (every `DisplayObject` or its' subclass) however if you need tweening functionality from the example - you'll find it here : http://www.libspark.org/wiki/BetweenAS3/en